# php-webdriver: wait for browser response after submitting form using click()

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

Aside from using `sleep()` in my test, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better strategy to explicitly wait for a form submission (POST) to complete before continuing with my assertions. Here's a very condensed version of what my test looks like, using phpunit together [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/) from Facebook).

```
function test_form_submission()
{   
    // setup
    $web_driver = new WebDriver();
    $session = $web_driver->session();
    $session->open('http://example.com/login');

    // enter data
    $session->element('css selector', 'input[name=email]')->value(array('value' => str_split('test@example.com')));
    $session->element('css selector', 'input[name=password]')->value(array('value' => str_split('testpassword')));

    // click button to submit form
    $session->element('css selector', 'button[name=submit]')->click();

    // How do I wait here until the click() above submits the form
    // so I can check that we correctly arrives at the destination below
    // without resorting to sleep()?

    // Confirm that login was successful because we landed on account page
    $this->assertSame('http://example.com/account', $session->url());

    // teardown
    $session->close();
}
```

Comment: So, when you execute this code now, the url in the second to last line (the assert) gives http://example.com/login instead of http://example.com/account? Presumably the Selenium server is supposed to wait out of itself till the page is load before looking for the element. The exception  to that are asynchronous requests, but yours looks pretty synchronous. Mind you, I'm using PHPUnit_Selenium to drive Selenium

Comment: Exactly. In fact I can take a screenshot at that moment as well, and see that I'm still on example.com/login, but if I sleep for 1 second, the assert passes, and the screenshot shows the page is now on example.com/account. I read that PHPUnit_Selenium was not quite up to running Selenium 2 (aka webdriver) so that's why I went with the approach above.

Answer (score 21):

[php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/) from Facebook has been rewritten in June 2013. You can wait for the URL easily like this.

```
// wait for at most 10 seconds until the URL is 'http://example.com/account'.
// check again 500ms after the previous attempt.
$driver->wait(10, 500)->until(function ($driver) {
  return $driver->getCurrentURL() === 'http://example.com/account';
})
```

Comment: What if the url is dynamically created? for example: site.com/item?id=123&color=black&size=small

Comment: Match the URL by regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I know this is a very old question, but as I stumbled upon it through Google I hope that this can still be useful for someone (maybe even the OP? :-)).

After quite some searching and reading articles and messages on Google Code, I found a solution that I think is quite ugly, but there is not really a good alternative. You can read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7K2QWGVNCYo) that it is impossible for WebDriver to detect when the page has loaded. So, we have to revert to waiting. Now, the OP is using Facebook's PHP WebDriver, which does not include waiting utilities AFAIK, but when using [this maintained clone](https://github.com/Element-34/php-webdriver), you get an implementation of WebDriverWait.

Now the question is: what do we wait for? You could wait for the URL to change, but this is in no way a reliable approach as the page probably is not loaded yet when the URL has changed already. Next option: wait for an element you know is on the page to be loaded to appear. That'll work, but what if you want to have a more generic approach? Luckily, I read a very good idea [in the thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/webdriver/7K2QWGVNCYo/XzKlsIhSU0kJ) I mentioned above. You can wait for an element that is on both pages to disappear and the reappear, for example the footer.

I implemented this just now and it seems to work. Below function can be passed your `$session` and will only return when the new page is loaded (or at least, the footer is available again).

```php
public static function waitForNextPage($pWDSession) {
    $aWait = new PHPWebDriver_WebDriverWait($pWDSession);
    // wait for footer to not be available anymore
    $aWait->until(
            function($pWDSession) {
                return (0 === count($pWDSession->elements(PHPWebDriver_WebDriverBy::CSS_SELECTOR, "#footer,#mx-footer")));
            }
        );
    // wait for footer to be available again
    $aWait->until(
            function($pWDSession) {
                return (0 < count($pWDSession->elements(PHPWebDriver_WebDriverBy::CSS_SELECTOR, "#footer,#mx-footer")));
            }
        );
}
```

You can obviously change the selector or use some other element, the idea remains the same.

I hope it helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `click()` it should be possible to use `clickAndWait()`, in order to wait until the next page has been loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure that works with php-webdriver. I get the following error: "Exception: clickAndWait is not a valid webdriver command."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Implicit Wait and Explicit Wait` to wait for a particular Web Element until it appears in the page. The wait period you can define and that is depends upon the application.

**Explicit Wait:**

An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. If the condition achieved it will terminate the wait and proceed the further steps.

Code:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(strEdit)));
```

Or

```
 WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
 .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
@Override
public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
    return d.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
}});
```

This waits up to 30 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it finds the element will return it in 0 - 30 seconds. WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other ExpectedCondition types.

You can use ExpectedConditions class as you need for the application.

**Implicit Wait:**

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available

Code:

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

One thing to keep in mind is that once the implicit wait is set - it will remain for the life of the WebDriver object instance

For more info use this link http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: I was specifically asking for a PHP solution that uses php-webdriver.