# Phpunit and Webdriver(Selenium2) - Can I run tests without selenium server like other languages?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'm using phpunit/phpunit-selenium for ui functional testing.
 I followed this brochure [phpunit-selenium on github](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium)

So far,I have to run the selenium standalone server as a http proxy, while I want to operate the browser directly  like Java.

Java code:

```
WebDriver diver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

but i didn't find a class named WebDriver in phpunit-selenium code.

Could anybody show me a code sample in PHP ,thanks

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem with Facebook WebDriver. I want to use Selenium WebDriver API, it means without any Selenium Server (ex: localhost:4444). Did you find a solution for this? Please share it to me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I misunderstood your question.
I guess facebook [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) can help you.
Search something like 'facebook php webdriver example' and you can find [code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466993/php-webdriver-wait-for-browser-response-after-submitting-form-using-click).

Old:

[Test of Phpunit Selenium on Github](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php) there are some examples.

And there are examples in  [official manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html#selenium.selenium2testcase.examples.WebTest.php).